# Where do you buy a whiteboard?

Tags: installation, hanging

I'm a math student, and I just entered grad school. I have a studio apartment, and there's one bigger-sized wall with no windows. I'd like to put a large whiteboard or chalkboard on it.

Where would you recommend I shop for such a thing? I have bought one for a previous apartment on Amazon, but perhaps it would be better/cheaper to avoid all the shipping hassle.

Once I have one, whom should I get to install it? (I have no experience with installing such things correctly, and I've just moved to a new city, so I don't really know anyone.)

Comment: Office-supply stores have whiteboards of various sizes from 16x20 to huge, with the bigger ones available through their catalogs. The big ones typically hang on french cleats; not hard to install. (Level the bar, put screws thru it into studs, drop the whiteboard onto it.)

Comment: FWIW, whiteboard markers work fine on glass too; I've sometimes used them to leave notes on my bathroom mirror, when I needed something more visible than soap.

Comment: http://www.dryeraseboard.com/2h2ag.html

Answer (score 1):

You can make your own.  Otherwise, questions about where to buy stuff are not in scope for this site.

If one of the walls can be repainted and is otherwise suitable as a whiteboard, just paint it over with [this](http://www.homedepot.com/p/Rust-Oleum-Specialty-27-oz-Gloss-White-Dry-Erase-Kit-241140/100670376).

[image]

More likely, as a renter, you can't modify the unit or paint it, so you'll have to buy a sheet of fiberboard, plywood, etc., hang it, and then paint it.

Comment: I see. I don't know of a Stack board for which this is on topic, then. Do you?

Comment: @EricAuld:  I don't know of such a stack exchange board, no.  You could try [Amazon](http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=dry%20erase%20board).  There are product reviews and discussions under particular products.